# 2007 Dodge Charger-Grinding, Scraping Noise Coming from front passenger side

Tags: noise, dodge, grinding, charger

I drive a 2007 Dodge Charger 3.5 liter. The first sign I noticed was sitting in a drive thru at a sit still, turning the steering wheel and hearing a noise, very similar to a creaky door, not super loud by any means but definitely noticeable. The next sign I noticed was the same (or nearly identical noise) going over speed bumps.

The first really worrying sign was about a week ago. I was driving down a straight road, going roughly 45mph, and out of nowhere a loud clanking, grinding noise abruptly started in what sounded like right in front of the passenger side front seat.

It lasted maybe 10 seconds and stopped as quick as it started. I could have sworn I had picked up and was dragging something under the car but when I checked there was nothing there. Then, earlier this evening, I had driven to pick up some carry out and when I returned to my car to head home, the same noise started as soon as I started rolling, it got louder the more I accelerated and changed pitch slightly going over bumps.

I drove roughly 3 miles and the entire time it made this clanking, grinding noise that ranged in intensity at a steady 45mph. It would stop making the noise at stop lights.

I finally pulled over and parked for a few moments, I reversed out of where I was and just like that, the noise is gone again!! The brakes don’t affect it at all so I know it’s not the brakes. Could it be the wheel bearing? Maybe worn bushings?

Comment: The two noises sound different. The large one sounds like heat shield to me... had it go few times in my van, just drops and suddenly makes a racket. The steering noise perhaps a balljoint

Comment: Would the racket come and go though? Or would it be constant until it got fixed?

Comment: In my case the racket would occur louder when accelerating, when hard turning right. When i coast and i am stopped no sound. It would always happen though, did not disappear for days and come back